# On Twitter on Firefox, when I click on the scrollbar in reply box, it thinks I want to quit (like I clicked on close)

Tags: windows, firefox, windows-11, twitter, windows-11-v22h2

Twitter on Firefox Browser 121.0 (64 bit) on Windows 11 Home v22H2 b22621.2715

Click Reply on any Tweet. Type something, press enter, next line again type & press enter. Keep repeating this until you get a **scroll bar** on the reply box.
[image]

Then click on the blank part under the scroll bar (you do this hoping, it will scroll down in the reply window). But Twitter interprets it as you wanting to discard the reply & go back to the main twitter page as if you clicked on the X on the top left of the reply window.

I do not see this behaviour on Edge browser. I also ran firefox with all extensions disabled but the problem still exists.

Is this a bug in Twitter, bug in Firefox or some settings somewhere?

Comment: What happens if you click the scroll bar higher up than that blue “Reply” button? If it is only in the area near the “Reply” button my guess is the Z-index for that “Reply” button is higher than the scroll bar’s Z-index. FWIW, if I recall correctly the scrollbar might not be a real scroll bar and instead a JavaScript element created by Twitter’s/X’s front end programming.

Comment: It happens irrespective of where I click below the scrollbar. If I click in the space below the spacebar, it happens & it happens only on Firefox. It happens even if I even try to drag the scrollbar down instead of clicking in the space below the scrollbar.

Comment: Good screen shot and clear statement of issue. It appear the top layer, i.e., *Save/Discard*, covers the scrollbar. Some ideas -- 1. Try scrolling using Ctrl-mouse wheel. 2. Test making the scrollbar wider: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/ujo1xy/how_to_increase_firefox_100_scrollbar_width/ . 3. Experiment using uBlockOrigin to remove part of that overly (which might have other consequences, of course).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 1) I am using touchpad 2) Tried wider scroll bar, doesn't work. I don't think it's a problem with Save/Discard covering. The Save/Discard dialog isn't there when I click below the scrollbar - it comes as a result of clicking below the scrollbar.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik does this seem like a Twitter bug or Firefox bug? If it's a firefox bug, then I can open a bug report on Firefox

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I am seeing it in 2 devices - one Windows 10 & one Windows 11

Comment: Yep, please submit that to Bugzilla, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ ! Note that some sites are said to *intentionally* use non-compliant HTML to make some browsers fail: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/b3em1o/is_google_purposely_breaking_firefox_to_force/ Could X be doing that??